# How to give 2 different background color for div's in loop in html

Tags: html, css

I have 2 type of background color boxes in my html, i have 1 box for loop in my php.

My problem is i have 4 rows each row have 2 different color boxes, for first row i try to manage it from css but i can't reverse order for 2nd row, please see snapshot below what i am want.

Sorry for my English but try to understand what i am saying?

[4 boxes in 2 row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Tiw.png)

In first row i manage from css dark and light background color but i can't reverse order in 2nd row i mean in 2nd row 1st box have light color and others are summitry wise dark then light.

Please tell me how i manage it from  css.

Here is my css and html code

```css
.teamColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 192px;
  background-color: #1a1e2a;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.teamColumn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 76px;
  height: 91px;
}

.teamColumn:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: #212634;
}
```

```html
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
```

Please give me advice how i can manage this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer above states, if you are able to wrap the divs that is probably the best solution. If not and you only have two rows, something like this may work:

```css
.teamColumn{
float:left; 
width:25%; 
position:relative; 
height:192px; 
background-color:#1a1e2a;
margin-bottom:2px;
}
.teamColumn:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"";
 bottom:0px;
 right:0;
 width:76px;
 height:91px;
}
.teamColumn:nth-child(8n+7){background-color:#212634;}
.teamColumn:nth-child(8n+5){background-color:#212634;}
.teamColumn:nth-child(8n+2){background-color:#212634;}
.teamColumn:nth-child(8n+4){background-color:#212634;}
```

```html
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik Svedin this is great but a another problem is for 3 row first 2 boxes is in same background color

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla updated answer for several rows now!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you wrap that each 4 divs? i think this problem will easily solve with it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but  teamColumn div loop in 1 row - <div class="teamColumn">&nbsp;</div>

Comment: i am not manage it from separate rows i have in 1 row max 20-24 boxes

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code :

```
    var items = ["#9062aa","#3fb4e9"];

 $(".CLASSNAME").each(function(index) {

   var color = items[index % items.length];
   $(this).css('background', color);

  });
```